# google autocomplete not supported by firefox android browser

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firefox, google-places-api, google-places

Recently while testing my website on different browser I stumbled upon a google location service api issue. Which is actually when I start typing in input ie on firefox mobile browser no suggestions are showing until I press **spac**e or **fullstop "."** Please see and test the sample [here](http://embed.plnkr.co/iHa94x38uMd8VkBs148D)

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="City" id="autocomplete"  gm-places-autocomplete ng-model="cityName">
```

javascript

```
$scope.lat = undefined;
$scope.lng = undefined;
$scope.$on('gmPlacesAutocomplete::placeChanged', function(){
      var location = $scope.cityName.getPlace().geometry.location;
      $scope.lat = location.lat();
      $scope.lng = location.lng();
      $scope.city = $scope.cityName.getPlace().name;
      $scope.place = $scope.cityName.getPlace();
      $scope.$apply();
      var componentForm = {
            locality: 'long_name',
            administrative_area_level_1: 'long_name',
            country: 'long_name'
        };

        var addCity, addProvince, addCountry;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.place.address_components.length; i++) {
            var addressType = $scope.place.address_components[i].types[0];
            if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = $scope.place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                if(addressType == 'locality')                    
                    {
                        $scope.newcity = addCity = val;
                    }
                if(addressType == 'administrative_area_level_1') 
                    {
                       $scope.newstate = $scope.stateName = addProvince = val;
                    }
                if(addressType == 'country')                     
                    {
                       $scope.newcountry = addCountry = val;
                    }
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: Please add some your code for review.

Comment: The problem lies when a user use autocomplete on firefox android browser. autocomplete doesn't show any suggestions while typing unless I input space or full stop.

Comment: In your updated plnkr link, autocomplete is working fine in firefox, no need to add "space" or "full stop".

Comment: I have attached a video [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzG6tpE9T5JaNk9fQ3pLVFRZbUk/view), please have a look. @JaromandaX

Comment: hd quality video [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/e4542ec8da3860e35ad4740973bac6e320170622060022/3ebc10) @VinitChouhan

Comment: I apologise - I can see what you mean - will remove all my comments

Comment: Its alright @JaromandaX do you have any idea why i am facing this issue.

Comment: @JaromandaX have you got any idea to resolve this issue..

Comment: @VinitChouhan have you got any solution regarding this...???

Comment: @ankitsuthar I have added code.